# Entity Framework - Generic Method to mark unchanged children to be deleted

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, generics, dbcontext

I'm working with EF4.3.1 and have implemented the DBContext.
I have several entities with parent-child relationships.  When I update an existing parent, I retreive the existing parent entity, make my changes, attach it to the context, mark it as modified and call SaveChanges().
If there are children entities on the parent, I follow a similiar process: find existing, make changes and mark them as modified.  I have a Generic method to loop through all of the children collections on my entity and add or attach them to the context, but I also need to remove any that are no longer in the parent collection.

For example, lets say my Parent Entity is a Program and each Program has a child collection of Locations.  When I first insert a Program it has 3 Locations.  When I later go to update the parent, the number of Locations has been reduced to 2.  My first method will mark the 2 remaining Locations as "Modified" and leave the 3 as "Unchanged".

Here's the method that I have so far, but it's slow, so I'm hoping for a better way:

```
<Extension()>
Public Sub MarkUnmodifiedChildrenAsDeleted(Of T As Class)(context As DbContext, theEntity As T)

    'get all of the children navigation properties of the Entity
    Dim navigationProperties As List(Of NavigationProperty) = context.GetNavigationProperties(Of T)().Where(Function(w) w.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity = RelationshipMultiplicity.Many).ToList

    'get the
    Dim primaryKeyProperty As PropertyInfo = FindPrimaryKeyProperty(context, theEntity)
    Dim pkValue As Integer = CInt(primaryKeyProperty.GetValue(theEntity, Nothing))

    For Each navigationProperty In navigationProperties
        Dim theList = context.Entry(theEntity).Collection(navigationProperty.Name).CurrentValue
        If theList.count > 0 Then
            'get the foreign key property on the child entity
            Dim foreignKeyName As String = DirectCast(navigationProperty.RelationshipType, AssociationType).ReferentialConstraints.Single().ToProperties.Single.Name

            'get the child type
            Dim propInfo As PropertyInfo = GetType(T).GetProperty(navigationProperty.Name)
            Dim propValue As Object = propInfo.GetValue(theEntity, Nothing)
            Dim theChildType As Type = propValue.GetType().GetGenericArguments()(0)

            'get a dbset that contains all of the Entities that match the Child Type in the database
            Dim theDBSet = context.Set(theChildType)
            For Each item In theDBSet
                Dim dbEE As DbEntityEntry = context.Entry(item)
                'if the entity is a child of the current Parent Entity and it's marked as UnChanged, mark it to Deleted
                If dbEE.Property(foreignKeyName).CurrentValue = pkValue AndAlso dbEE.State = EntityState.Unchanged Then
                    dbEE.State = EntityState.Deleted
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I think most of the pain is in `For Each item In theDBSet`. Are there so many occasions in your application where this happens that such a generic approach really helps? The reflection parts won't help performance either.

Comment: @GertArnold - Thanks for your response, I certainly agreed!  The `For Each` is definitely a weak point.  I agree that it would be nice (performance wise) to skip the generic approach and I may end up having to go that route, however, I was hoping someone else knew of a better generic method.  There are enough occasions now that going with the non-generic approach would feel almost wrong, especially if I added more scenarios.